# How to view URL of the links in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

I am using `[[LINK][DESCRIPTION]]` format to define hyperlinks in org-mode.

> Org recognizes plain URIs, possibly wrapped within angle brackets, and
> activate them as clickable links. The general link format, however,
> looks like this:
>
> `[[LINK][DESCRIPTION]]`

When I write `[[LINK][DESCRIPTION]]` it automatically becomes `DESCRIPTION`. Would it be possible keep it as its expanded version where I can see the URL as well in the buffer?

Comment: `C-h v org-link-descriptive`: customize the variable and  set it to nil.

Comment: @NickD Thanks it was exactly what I was looking for. Would it be possible to set `org-link-descriptive` true and nil (toggle in between) via keybinding?

Comment: Yes, of course: since nobody has really answered yet, you can add it to your question (as a general rule, modifying questions after the fact - except for clarifications and fixing typos - is highly discouraged). I'll answer when I find the time, unless somebody beats me to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operative variable is `org-link-descriptive` (it was called `org-descriptive-links` in earlier versions of Org mode). Its doc string (`C-h v org-link-descriptive` says:

> Non-nil means Org displays descriptive links.
>
> E.g. [[https://orgmode.org][Org website]] is be displayed as
> "Org Website", hiding the link itself and just displaying its
> description.  When set to nil, Org displays the full links
> literally.
>
> You can interactively set the value of this variable by calling
> ‘org-toggle-link-display’ or from the "Org > Hyperlinks" menu.

That simultaneously answers the question in the question and the additional question in a comment about using a function to toggle it. The only additional thing to do is to add a keybinding:

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c z") #'org-toggle-link-display)
```